What is this usage of いざなってみたら


It seems to be the verb 誘う but I don't think any of the meaning fits? I'm gonna guess みたら is "After I tried to do x" but I don't get the verb.

いざ is basically an interjection used to rally spirits before an important event (typically a battle), similar to saying "Let's rock!" or "Now is the hour!". It has a slightly archaic tone, so using it in this sense in modern everyday conversation might sound exaggerated. It's mainly used in fiction by samurai or knights, and it's also found in sport-related catchphrases. See also: What is the meaning/usage of いざ?
The phrase "いざ～してみると" is a set expression, and this いざ also implies that the action was started with some determination, excitement or expectation. It's typically followed by a result that contradicts the expectation. For example, いざ箱を開けてみたら空だった ("When I (finally) opened the box, it was empty") suggests that there was some hesitation or excitement before opening the box. In your example, なる refers to whatever this person was hoping to become in this context (大人, ヒーロー, etc.), which is not specified in the pasted page.
Additionally, いざ can refer to a rare moment when something is needed. いざという時に備えて貯金する means "saving money for emergencies", and いざとなると役に立たない means "useless when it's most needed".

The verb is なる (成る,to become). いざ here is an adverb (1 and 2) and is used here as something analog to "then" or "finally". The sentence roughly translates to:
"Then when I/he finnaly became (free)"
